# QFileDialog : get file name

Tags: qt, qfiledialog

I am using Qt 5 and QFileDialog. I want to restrict user to give forward slash (/) in file name.

I have below code for QFileDialog to save the file name.

```
QFileDialog saveAsdialog(this);
QString filename = saveAsdialog.getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save
file"), ".", tr("Files (*.csv)"));
```

In dialog, if user gives file name "abc.csv" in "download" folder then "getSaveFileName" returns "/home/user/Downloads/abc.csv" which is correct.

But my question is when user give forward slash in file  name (/) then it is not behaving correctly.

e.g. If user want to give file name "abc/xyz.csv" then i am not getting the correct file name.

How to get the correct file name "abc/xyz.csv" when user click "OK"?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what do you get in that case, and what is your expectation?

Comment: My expectation is when user give filename as "abc/xyz.csv" in dialog, i want to extract the filename when user press ok button and close the dialog. I am getting full path like "/home/user/Downloads/abc/xyz.csv". From this path i am not able to find file name given by user. How should we get the exact filename given by user in the dialog once user close dialog?

Comment: @Neel At least you can derive `QFileDialog` and reimplement `accept` method with needed checks.

Answer (score 2):

Please watch on this [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words).

As you can see, `/` character is prohibited in file name. So file name `abc/xyz.csv` is incorrect.

Also you can always check wich is current directory in file dialog, and based on this information you can track selected file name. Try this:

```
QFileDialog saveAsdialog(this);
QString curDir(QDir('.').absolutePath());
connect(&saveAsdialog, &QFileDialog::directoryEntered, [&curDir](const QString& dir) {
    curDir = dir;
});
// We cann't use static member getSaveFileName
//QString filename = saveAsdialog.getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save file"), ".", tr("Files (*.csv)"));
//here manual saveAsdialog setup
...........
if (saveAsdialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {

    QString filename = saveAsdialog.selectedFiles().first(); //add check that list is not empty!!!
    QString f = filename.replace(curDir, "");
}
```

Comment: In different dialogs user may or not type `/` in the filename. Native Windows dialog doesn't allow it at all. Qt dialog allows it and treats `abc/xyz.csv` as file `xyz.csv` in `abc` subdirectory of the current directory. But it doesn't check the `abc` existence. **P.S.**: not sure that it is a big problem; just show an error if you cannot open the file.

Comment: You are right. Just for you information - error opening file will come only in linux but in Mac OS "/" will be converted to ":" in the filename. In Mac filename abc/xyz.csv will connverted by Qt abc:xyz.csv. That might be one work around but is there any way to extract filename only from the dialog when user close the dialog ?  e.g. If user give file name "abc/xyz.csv" and save in folder "/home/user/Downloads" then i am getting full path like "/home/user/Downloads/abc/xyz.csv" and from this i am not able to find exact file  name give by user in dialog after user close the dialog.

Comment: @Evgeny. Thanks for the comments.I have tried your patch but I want the dialog of save file not open file. In save file dialog, user will enter the name of the file. I have tried your solution but it is asking for open file from existing folder.

Comment: Thanks Evgeny.. I got the answer for your comments. I have to set "AcceptMode" to work for save as dialog. Thanks again for your reply.